# Permission denied when docker build

Tags: docker, bitnami, fluentd

I know there are a lot of questions with similar title but none of them is similar to my issue. My problem is simple, I'm trying to install a few packages in my dockerfile using the command `install_packages`. This results in a permission denied error stating `/bin/sh: 1: install_packages: Permission denied`

I've tried adding `USER 0` and `USER root` but none of them worked. Below is my Dockerfile. What am I doing wrong?. Also saw a similar issue in github but the solution provided there didn't work for me.
Similar Issue: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/issues/230

Dockerfile: (Errors out in the sixth command)

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster
LABEL maintainer "Bitnami <containers@bitnami.com>"
USER root

ENV HOME="/" \
    OS_ARCH="amd64" \
    OS_FLAVOUR="debian-10" \
    OS_NAME="linux"

COPY prebuildfs /
# Install required system packages and dependencies
RUN install_packages ca-certificates curl ghostscript gzip imagemagick libc6 libgcc1 libgmp-dev libjemalloc-dev libncurses5-dev libncurses6 libreadline-dev libreadline7 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libtinfo6 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev procps tar zlib1g zlib1g-dev
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "ruby" "2.6.6-0" --checksum ecadce77e40822926c69f76cc11437954dd068793548c3f0a21007f9c4fafed3
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "gosu" "1.12.0-0" --checksum 582d501eeb6b338a24f417fededbf14295903d6be55c52d66c52e616c81bcd8c
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "fluentd" "1.10.4-0" --checksum 1428d81be002b7124db38326c73ebe9980e5b3c94a15e3054cdbdff9f8aa3979
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential -y && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

COPY rootfs /
RUN /opt/bitnami/scripts/fluentd/postunpack.sh
ENV BITNAMI_APP_NAME="fluentd" \
    BITNAMI_IMAGE_VERSION="1.10.4-debian-10-r1" \
    GEM_HOME="/opt/bitnami/fluentd" \
    PATH="/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/fluentd/bin:$PATH"

#GEM Installation
WORKDIR /opt/bitnami/fluentd
RUN gem install jwk-tool
RUN fluent-gem install 'fluent-plugin-azure-storage-append-blob'
#RUN fluent-gem install 'fluent-plugin-encrypt'
RUN gem install fluent-plugin-jwt-filter && \
    gem install json -v "~> 1.8" && \
    gem install fluent-plugin-kubernetes && \
    gem install fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter && \
    gem uninstall tzinfo -v 2.0.2
#RUN jwk_tool -g -k key
COPY ./key.pub /opt/bitnami/fluentd/key.pub

EXPOSE 24224 5140

WORKDIR /opt/bitnami/fluentd
#USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/fluentd/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/fluentd/run.sh" ]
```

Comment: what's the result from `whoami` before running the `install_packages` script?

Comment: @abestrad root. bitnami base image have been updated 11 hours ago. So I think they have messed up something in that update coz the same dockerfile was working a few weeks back

Comment: it might be the way the install_packages script operates, many of the containers created and maintained by them at the end are working as non-root containers.

Comment: @abestrad Yes this is also working as non-root. you can see the `USER 1001` line in the end that I have commented out. So nothing seems wrong with my dockerfile right?

Comment: What's the result of `ls -la /usr/sbin/install_packages`? Can you run it before the first `RUN` command?

Answer (score 5):

The "**install_packages**" file within the user path directory might not be set as executable by default. You can try making it executable "chmod +x /usr/sbin/install_packages" and try again. It worked for me.